# Jenkins jobs slow. Is it I/O related?

Tags: ruby, linux, shell, jenkins, ubuntu-14.04

We have several jenkins pipeline jobs that are taking much longer to complete than we expect.  Specific steps seem to "hang" for unwarranted periods of time.  Running those same steps manually on another system runs significantly faster.

One example job is a step that uses Ruby to recurse through a bunch of directories and performs a shell command on each file in those directories.  Running on our Ubuntu 14.04 Jenkins system takes about 50 **minutes**.  Running the same command on my desktop Mac runs in about 10 **seconds**.

I did some experimentation on the Jenkins builder by running the Ruby command at the command prompt and had the same slow result that Jenkins had.  I also removed Ruby from the equation by batching up each of the individual shell commands Ruby would have run and put them in a shell script to run each shell command sequentially.  That took a long time as well.

I've read some posts about STDERR blocking may be the reason.  I've then done some experimentation with redirecting STDERR and STDOUT to /dev/null and the commands will finish in about 20 seconds.  That is what I would expect.

My questions are: 
1. Would these slowdowns in execution time be the result of some I/O blocking?
2. What is the best way to fix this?  Some cases I may want the output so redirecting to /dev/null is probably not going to work.  Is there a kernel or OS level change I can make?

Running on Ubuntu 14.04 Amazon EC2 instance R3.Large.

```
Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-108-generic x86_64)
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-linux]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. **Transferring huge amounts of data between slave and master leads to performance problems** indeed. This applies for storing build artifacts as well as for massive amounts of console output.

For console output, **the performance penalty is particularly big if you use the [timestamper plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Timestamper)**. If enabled for your job, try disabling that first.

Otherwise, I'd **avoid huge amounts of console output in general**. Try to restrict console output to very high job-level information that (in case of failure) provides links to further "secondary" logfile data.

Using I/O redirection (as you already did) is the proper way to accomplish that, e.g.

```
mycommand 2>mycommand.stderr.txt 1>mycommand.stdout.txt
```

This will *always* work (except for *very* special cases where you may need to select command-specific options to redirect a console output stream that a command explicitly creates on its own).